# How to copy Windows EC2 instances to S3 bucket in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am not able to find a find documents showing how can I copy a Windows instance to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Can any one help me with step by step approach to do this and suggest some of the links?

Comment: You can not copy AMIs to s3.  You can either create a snapshot of your volumes or create another image (AMI).

Comment: Thank you, Can I get some of the links related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy a Windows instance to S3"? This could mean several things. *What* are you copying, and for what purpose? How would you intend using it once it is in S3?

Comment: Creating AMI's helped me, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not copy AMIs to s3. You can either create a snapshot of your volumes or create another image (AMI).

I assume you're trying to create a backup of your AMIs.  So, there are some alternatives for doing that.

- Create a new AMI from an existing running image. **Reference:** [Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Windows AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html)

> ## Creating a Windows AMI from a Running Instance
>
> You can create an AMI using the AWS Management Console or the command line. The following diagram summarizes the process for creating an Amazon EBS-backed AMI from a running EC2 instance. Start with an existing AMI, launch an instance, customize it, create a new AMI from it, and finally launch an instance of your new AMI. The steps in the following diagram match the steps in the procedure below. If you already have a running Amazon EBS-backed instance, you can go directly to step 4.
>
> [image]

You can create images using the AWS CLI command [create-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html)

---

- Create Snapshots of your volumes, these snapshots will be stored behind the scenes in s3. **Reference:** [Creating an Amazon EBS Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)

[image]

You can create EBS snapshots using the AWS CLI command [create-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html)

## + Resources

- [Copying an Amazon EBS Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html)
- [Copying an AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html)